# Flask-login not remembering user on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, flask

Flask-login doesn't seem to remember the user in chrome after calling 'login_user(user)'. It does work for safari and other browser, but not on chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you're developping on "localhost" or "testsite" domains, without any valid top-level domain. Chrome doesn't, by design decision, store cookies on the "localhost" domain, which means no session cookie will be stored there.
see : 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

The solution is to create an alias on your etc/hosts file such as : 
127.0.0.1 localhost.com

and work on "localhost.com" domain.

Comment: Also check SERVER_NAME config value in flask config. Sometimes this could be the root of the problem. More on config http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/